# Without Proxy page can't use IE8 and IE9 for Editing and Buffer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing, browser, internet-explorer

The server where my editing application is hosted does not allow a proxy page because of outgoing calls restriction. This makes it difficult for IE8 and IE9 since using CORS is not an option as there is limited support for these browsers. The limitation is that they do not support POST when using XDomainRequest and also there is a URL length limit. What is the best practice to POST Cross Origin messages from these browsers. Even if I write custom code I would like to leverage the heavy lifting done by esri's tasks like the ApplyEdits event handlers.